# How does a fidget spinner spin for so long?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

I assume that this has something to do with the ball bearings in the "arms" of a fidget spinner:

[image]
([Source](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81OfMp0cWtL._SL1500_.jpg))

What I am confused about is that when you spin a fidget spinner, I would think that the only ball bearing in action is the one in the center around which the fidget spinner rotates. But then, why would there be ball bearings in the arms?

So how do these ball bearings affect the rotation of the fidget spinner?

Comment: The ball bearings in the arms are just to make it heavier.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for your comment! This kind of makes sense, but wouldn't it be easier to simply use a metal cylinder then?

Comment: What is your question?  The law of inertia says things keep going unless there's an opposing force, which in this case is friction.  Minimize friction and maximize initial momentum to get the longest spin time.

Comment: At a guess: because they already have a supply of ball bearings, and a machine that inserts ball bearings. Maybe they liked the way it looked. I don't really know.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft As stated in the last paragraph, I would like to know if the ball bearings in the arms affect the rotation, and if yes, how.

Comment: @user253751 I think that your first comment should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ball bearings in the arms are just to make it heavier.

Why ball bearings? I don't really know, but I guess it's because they already have a supply of ball bearings and a machine that inserts ball bearings. Maybe they also like the way it looks. Maybe they like the way you can grab the inside of one of the ball bearings with your fingers and swing the fidget spinner around.

I have seen fidget spinners that lit up and used batteries in the arms, and ones that have marbles in the arms, so they don't *have* to have ball bearings.

Comment: The ball bearings in the arms aren't _just_ for weight. If that was all, then you could make the thing more cheaply by using solid steel balls or discs. No, the ball bearings also serve the "fidgit" purpose—something for idle fingers to play with.